# Key column 'cat_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

I have table `category` with

```
cat_id
category
```

and table `products` with

```
prod_id
products
```

and another table `product_category` with

```
pkey
index
```

I have tried to add foreign keys on `product_category` with this:

```
ALTER TABLE product_category
ADD FOREIGN KEY (cat_id)
REFERENCES categories(cat_id)
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your table is called `category` (singular) and you are trying to reference a table `categories` (plural), on top of that you are not using the field name from the table product_category.

See the following example that does what you want. (I have changed the fields name from product_category around so it is more clear what to use where).

```
mysql> create table category (cat_id int, category varchar(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.39 sec)

mysql> create table products (prod_id int, product varchar(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)

mysql> create table product_category (pc_prod_id int, pc_cat_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> alter table product_category add foreign key (pc_cat_id) references category(cat_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Your table `product_category` does not have a `cat_id` field, so you cannot add a reference.
Add that field with the same datatype `categoriy.cat_id` has and try again.

What [storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) do you use? Keep in mind that MyISAM does not support [checking for foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html).

I guess `pkey` is supposed to be a reference to `prod_id`? Naming it `prod_id` or something similar would make it clearer what it is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

You must add cat_id first in the table, and then try to add foreign key reference.

```
alter table Table_name
add col_name data_type constraints
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is how should be fixed :

we have two tables,

```
table1( id_table1 int primary key, field int)ENGINE=INNODB;
table2( id_table2 int primary key, id_table1 int, field2 int)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

if you want to put the primary key of `table1` in `table2`, you have to declare in
`table2` the `id_table1`

Like this :`id_table1 integer`

and then write your `foreign key(id_table1)` references `table1(id_table1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your table product_category does not contain column that you have specified in query..
add it and run this query ....

there is no issue with query ..